# Compute Engine (wordpress website) crashed, wrong SSL command and space issue

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have been running my wordpress website on Google cloud the last 12 months with no issue. VM instance - using SSH on Apache server.

My website went down yesterday and I could not access it through wordpress. I am trying to do everything myself and I am a beginner when it comes to learning the back end functionality.

So I went into my google cloud and ssl’d onto my server. I though it might be an outdated certificate and I entered an incorrect command (see photo attached - I didn't include my actual email and domain name stupidly, copied and pasted it from the internet). And now I am getting an error saying mysql is not working. I think there may be a space issue too.

When I try go to my website I get and

> Error establishing a database connection

So my questions are - did I mess up anything from entering the wrong code in SSL? And how do I solve the space issue and get my site running again.

I just tried to updated my server size through google console - but gettting the error in the screenshot that it can't connect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just managed to update the size of the disk using the instructions.

When I try to access my website through url it is saying the below error message.
I think the incorrect code is I entered the other day in SSL per the original post. 

Could you please let me know if you have any solutions?                                            
 This site can’t be reached
**** refused to connect.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: You stopped your services. Have you try to start them with `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start` command?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter the following content into the script and save it. Ensure to replace the ‘Domain’ placeholder with your actual domain name, and the ‘Email-Address’ placeholder with your email address.

For Apache:

```
 #!/bin/bash
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop apache
sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --tls --email="EMAIL-ADDRESS" --domains="DOMAIN" --path="/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt" renew --days 90
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start apache
```

Please go through this [link](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/) for more information.

2. In some cases, the certificates aren’t properly uploaded to the server, so the server is still using the dummy ones. Perform the following checks:

Check that the certificate files are located as below for Apache:

```
Certificate: /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt
Key: /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key
CA: /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server-ca.crt.
```

3. Please follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache#troubleshooting) for connection refused error.

If you still face issues after following the above, do mention the details about the error to narrow down the issue.